# how to extract all matches number

Tags: regex, perl

I want to extract all 14 digit numbers from a webpage but i am getting only one result

```
use LWP::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url = 'example.com'; #input url
my $as = `curl --silent '$url' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; In grep OS X 10.9; rv:24.

if ($as =~ m/(\d{12,14})/g) {   
    print STDERR Dumper($as);
}

$as =~ m{(\d{12,14})};

my $upc=$1;

print "$upc\n";
```

is printing only one number

Comment: Is that `@as` a typo?

Comment: Then what is the value of this `$as`?

Comment: $as is url.I am extracting webpage data and want every 12,14 digit number

Comment: Please include the real value of `$as` in your question.

Comment: check now ...i made changes in question

Comment: Still no value of `$as`. Anyway, try the answer given by @M42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
my @results = $as =~ m{\b(\d{12,14})\b}g;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the global flag, but I am unfamiliar with method of specifying the reges. I expect them to start/end with "/", where you just the flag "g" i.e.

```
/\d{12,14}/g
```